# Touch/Drag Heuristics have changed in iOS 6. Any way to get the old behavior back?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, onclick, touch, ios6

Our iPad app uses a webkit UI for a lot of the user interaction, and we are now fielding complaints from users that in iOS 6, the UI is ignoring their touches. We've done side-by-side comparisons, and are now quite certain that whereas a touch-small-drag-release gesture in iOS 5 would trigger on onclick event, a touch-small-drag-release gesture in iOS 6 does not. Thus, in iOS 6, you need to be very careful to never move your finger while pressing a button on the UI. (Or, perhaps they just changed the definition of "small" in small-drag.)

We believe that disabling multi-touch gestures in the Settings > General page improves things somewhat, although we're not convinced this isn't a placebo effect.

As a test, I tried removing the scroll-preventing:

```
  document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
```

from our code, but it made no difference (other than making it really obvious that the drag events are dragging).

My next idea is to go through and change everywhere that we rely on onclick to instead rely on ontouchstart, but, well, yuck. (Particularly, yuck, in cases where we also need the same code to work in desktop browsers.)

Are we alone here? I'm not finding any complaints about this in my searches. Any clever ideas?

Comment: Some more observations:
1. This is more of an issue with <div> elements with onclick handlers, and less of an issue with <a> elements with onclick handlers.
2. I've been switching to using ontouchend instead of onclick, and while it works, it does lead to some strange results. For example, in one UI we have a <select> element that appears in the same place the user just touched, and the select would self-trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not alone!

We hit a similar problem in our new game [Blue Pilot](http://www.fivedeer.com/blue-pilot), while we extend the support to iPhone 5.  We are now handling both events.